# How to document inconsistent returns with JSDoc?

Tags: javascript, documentation, jsdoc

Is it possible to add `@return` JSDoc annotation for a function with inconsistent returns?

```
/**
* @param {Number} a
* @param {Number} b
* @return {Number}
* */
function sum (a, b) {
  if (a < b) return false; //here we have a Boolean
  return a + b; //and here a Number
}
```

Note:

1. I already know that **this is bad**.
2. I **won't do it** in my code.
3. **Just interested** in how everyone handle this issue (in other ways than refactoring).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an example [right there in the JSDoc `@returns` documentation](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-returns.html):

> **The return value can have different types**
>
> ```
> /**
>  * Returns the sum of a and b
>  * @param {Number} a
>  * @param {Number} b
>  * @param {Boolean} retArr If set to true, the function will return an array
>  * @returns {Number|Array} Sum of a and b or an array that contains a, b and the sum of a and b.
>  */
> function sum(a, b, retArr) {
>     if (retArr) {
>         return [a, b, a + b];
>     }
>     return a + b;
> }
> ```

E.g., use `|`, as you do other times the type may vary.

Comment: Cool, I've missed it. I'll accept your answer after 10 minutes cooldown